# Drivers license and motor vehicle registration data for professional drivers

Tags: api

Is there a known API to pull driver's license data and MVR data for professional drivers, such as those working for freight forwarding companies?

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: In the US, the police have access to driver's license and motor vehicle registration data. I don't think it's available for purposes other than law enforcement.

Answer (score -1):

In the USA, you could try this api :
http://www.vehicleregistrationapi.com/

It works on license plates, not drivers license numbers.

Comment: This is a paid service, and so, not "open data"